# I am trying to store form values in local storage on submitting form. now i want that all input tags should be cleared once i clicked on submit button

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var formHandle = document.forms.infoForm;

formHandle.onsubmit = processForm;
function processForm() {
    var formName = formHandle.f_name;
    var formColor = formHandle.f_color;
    localStorage.setItem('name', formName.value);
    localStorage.setItem('color', formColor.value);
    document.getElementById('newMsgBox').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + localStorage.getItem('name') + ' !';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('color');
   
    return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Storing Data</title>
    <style>body{background:#c0c0c0;}</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Customizable Interface</h1>

<!-- WELCOME BOX -->
    <div id="output">
        <h2 id="newMsgBox">Welcome!</h2>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="lab9.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

<!--USER PREFERENCES FORM-->
    <form name="infoForm" action="#" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Customize Your Experience</legend>
        
            <!--GET USER NAME-->
            <p>
                <label for="inName" >What is your name?</label>
                <input type="text" id="inName" name="f_name"/>
            </p>
        
            <!-- GET COLOUR-->
            <p>
                <label for="inColor" >What is your favourite colour? </label>
                <input type="color" id="inColor" name="f_color" />
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Click to save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

<!--DELETE COOKIES-->
    <p><input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Delete your Stored Information" /></p>

<script src="lab9.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> what should i do to clear out form once i click on "Click to save" button. and Welcome message should change from "Welcome!" to "Welcome entered name!".
> on clicking on delete , local storage value should be removed
> after deleting local storage, page should look like exactly same as before

Answer (score 0):

All form elements have an inbuilt reset() method. Please refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) to understand how these elements work in order to properly use them.

What your snippet needs is -

```
formHandle.reset();
```

I have fixed your snippet. **Please read the comments in the snippet too.**

```js
var formHandle = document.forms.infoForm;
var deleteBtn = document.getElementById('btnDel');

function processForm(event) {
  // use the "event" to prevent submitting the form "i.e. calling the URL '#'"
  // if your requirement is to only use those form values and update the UI
  // store them in localstorage and have no backend/server interaction, then
  // you don't want to submit the form at all.
  event.preventDefault();
  var formName = formHandle.f_name;
  var formColor = formHandle.f_color;

  // local storage calls would fail on StackOverflow - so commenting them out
  // and adding alternate commands to demonstrate the required changes.

  //localStorage.setItem('name', formName.value);
  //localStorage.setItem('color', formColor.value);
  //document.getElementById('newMsgBox').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + localStorage.getItem('name') + ' !';
  //document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('color');

  document.getElementById('newMsgBox').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + formName.value + ' !';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = formColor.value;
  formHandle.reset(); // this is what will reset the form!
}

function clearAll(event) {
  // remove from localStorage
  //localStorage.removeItem('name');
  //localStorage.removeItem('color');
  // resetting to original state
  document.getElementById('newMsgBox').innerHTML = 'Welcome!';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#c0c0c0';
}

formHandle.onsubmit = processForm;
deleteBtn.onclick = clearAll;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Storing Data</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #c0c0c0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Customizable Interface</h1>

  <!-- WELCOME BOX -->
  <div id="output">
    <h2 id="newMsgBox">Welcome!</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="lab9.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!--USER PREFERENCES FORM-->
  <form name="infoForm" action="#" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Customize Your Experience</legend>

      <!--GET USER NAME-->
      <p>
        <label for="inName">What is your name?</label>
        <input type="text" id="inName" name="f_name" />
      </p>

      <!-- GET COLOUR-->
      <p>
        <label for="inColor">What is your favourite colour? </label>
        <input type="color" id="inColor" name="f_color" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Click to save" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <!--DELETE COOKIES-->
  <p><input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Delete your Stored Information" /></p>

  <script src="lab9.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use return false in for processForm() function. Form on submit by default will refresh the page and all fields will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form, the page should be refreshed by default. But, you can also try to reload by hand.

```
var formHandle = document.forms.infoForm;

formHandle.onsubmit = processForm;
function processForm() {
    var formName = formHandle.f_name;
    var formColor = formHandle.f_color;

    if (!formName.value || !formColor.value) {

        return false;

    }
    else {

        localStorage.setItem('name', formName.value);
        localStorage.setItem('color', formColor.value);
        document.getElementById('newMsgBox').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + localStorage.getItem('name') + ' !';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('color');
            
        // refresh the page
        location.reload();
    }
        

    return false;
}
```